# Browser back button is not working in Blazor web-server

Tags: browser, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to go previous page when the user clicks on the browser back button. When I navigate another page, I can not go to the last page by using the browser back button. So, can anyone help me find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello Tanvi, can you share your razor code here?

Comment: Your question as is stands cannot be answered.   The back button does work as normal in Blazor so your problem is specific to what you are doing or the browser you are using, and we don't know what that is because you haven't told us. Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that every state that you want to show up in next/back is differentiated by a route change navigated to by NavigationManager.

If you make a page /somePage and you let the user step through several choices, and then the user navigates (using the URL bar) then hits the back button on the browser, they will go back to /somePage and not back to the choices they made.

If you make a page /somePage and each time the user makes a choice they are navigated to a new page using NavigationManager, for example /somePage/someSelection, then when they hit back they will go back to /somePage/someSelection. This requires you to load data on subpage choices on init based on optional page route parameters, but the tradeoff is having browser navigations that are part of next/back.